# Почему выдает такую ошибку pygame.mixer.music.load('Powerup2.wav') pygame.error: Couldn't open 'Powerup2.wav'

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import os
import time
import random
pygame.font.init()
pygame.mixer.init() 
pygame.mixer.music.load('Powerup2.wav')
```

Comment: Файл 'Powerup2.wav' находиться в одном каталоге с основной программой?

Answer (score 0):

Укажите абсолютный путь к файлу или откройте его через os. Но вообще на windows в python можно указывать и относительный - проверьте, что файл лежит в той же папке